# How to maintain multiple collection and view instances in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

**brief structure of my app**

-->master view

-->model

-->Collection

-->SubView

Master view create many subview with collection instances.

**masterview inside**

```
newTable:function(){

var collection=new Collection;
var subview=new SubView({collection:collection});

}
```

1. I need to get send requests from server.
2. I need to update collections according to response.

for those requirements

1. I need to maintain the which request from which collection
2. which collection have to update on response.

How can I maintain requests and responses?

Answer (score 0):

The point of Backbone.sync is to handle that for you. When you have a collection, you can perform a fetch on it like this:

```
 collection.fetch()
```

The collection will then make an ajax request to its url via Backbone.sync and update itself when it returns. It will then trigger the "reset" event to let you know that it has been updated. Bind the subviews to the "reset" event on their respective collection like this:

```
SubView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = this.options.collection;
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    }
})
```

This particular subview should be instantiated like this `new SubView({collection: yourCollection})`. It will then render itself when you do a `yourCollection.fetch()`. You can of course bind to any function you like!

Comment: See the edits in question, I have to update collections according to responses. not urls no ajax

Comment: How do you make this request? As a separate ajax request?

Comment: treat it as a module send requests to the initialiser what ever it, either websockets or ajax etc..

Comment: Then you probably need to override sync, either Backbone.sync or the individual collection.sync. Not sure I understand how you mean though.